# Menubar item not displaying properly CSS Error

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**I have made a few changes in my wordpress theme, changed positions of two menu bar. top menu & primary menu.**

I tried to make it work but it didn't.

> My Top Menu bar with home button, & other items and its sub item are
>   not working properly, they mix with secondary menu bar's items

i think need make css changes but i don't know what.Can anyone can help me

[www.techral.com](http://www.techral.com)

Comment: You should clearly state what you were trying to accomplish and what happened instead. "Not working properly" is not good enough, because we can't see what you had in mind.

Comment: I will follow it..You are correct.

Comment: You both saved my day... I was missed with it, Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `position: relative` for the css rule `nav.top-menu`, you should be good to go.

```
nav.top-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Otherwise, check your `z-index:13` => `z-index:0` for `nav.top-menu`, it's the reason for overlaying your primary menu's dropdown submenu.

Answer (score 0):

increase z-index : 15 on .primary-menu class

```
.primary-menu {
position: relative;
z-index: 15;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-moz-transform: translateZ(0);
-ms-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be great.